# cocos2d version 0.8 sprite animation

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, cocos2d-iphone

I built an app on cocos2d version 0.8 and now can not find an online tutorial on how to animate a sprite. I don't want to have to switch the whole app over. Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.8/annotated.html

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.8.2/index.html - there is a link to programming guide

Comment: I've been trying to put the code together but i keep getting errors :(